# Trouble installing TextBlob for Python

Tags: python, textblob

I am new to programming, and I'm trying to install the TextBlob library for Python to help me do some stuff. Sadly, I'm having trouble installing TextBlob, let alone use it. I am using Windows, which seems to make things more difficult. I wish I could just run the Linux commands or whatever they are that everybody uses. Anyway

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Forked the Textblob program from [here.](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob)
2. Copied the entire repository to my desktop, and opened the folder up.
3. Using Command Prompt, ran "Python C:\Users...\setup.py install"

Command Prompt spits back-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\TextBlob\setup.py", line 56, in <module>
    __version__ = find_version("textblob/__init__.py")
  File "C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\TextBlob\setup.py", line 45, in find_version
    with open(fname, 'r') as fp:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'textblob/__init__.py'
```

And I have no idea what to do or how to fix this. Shouldn't this fresh download of TextBlob have the ability to install? What am I messing up?

Comment: Why are you doing that rather than following the instructions in the readme, which say to run `pip install -U textblob`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman maybe he does not have pip installed?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for you help. I just installed setup tools and pip which was a struggle (found at this link http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) but now I'm not sure where to run the command "pip install-U textblob". I typed it into Command prompt, and is it not recognized. When should I be putting this. Thanks very much

Comment: Hi Sasa, I did not have pip but I just installed it. Hopefully correctly :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are expected to be **in** the directory when installing.  Try:

```
cd C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\TextBlob
python setup.py install
```

**BTW** try to get out of the habit of saving things to the desktop.  You should **only** have short cuts on there especially on corporate machines as they often save the desktop on shutdown to the network and load it on startup - this slows things down a lot when there are files and directories on there.