# Cannot Import Textblob In Jupyter After successfully installing it

Tags: python

I have downloaded and installed textblob using pip and now while i am importing it on jupyter notebook i get an error as:

> No module named 'textblob'

Have checked [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942081/i-cant-import-textblob-package) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575100/textblob-installation-in-windows) amongst other similar thread on SO but following the recommended steps i am not still able to download it.

Running CMD as an administrator i am getting this error while trying to load the package again:

> Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade

This is how i am calling it in jupyter -

```
from textblob import TextBlob
```

pip version - pip 19.0.3

Comment: Do you've 2 versions on python installed in your system ?

Comment: there is only 1 version.checked the environment variables. C:\Users\51613014>python
Python 3.7.2

Comment: Are you able to import textblob in command line ? if yes, then stop the jupyter process and restart the kernel. It should work ! Otherwise, uninstall and install using : conda install -c conda-forge textblob

Comment: i installed it via conda and it worked. not sure why it was not working even after loading successfully in pip